# MongoDB GridFS Error

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework-2.1, gridfs

I'm using gridFS and it appears after I write a file, if I immediately do a read to try to find it mongoDB throws a runtime exception but it seems intermittent.

The java code that causes it is:

```
List<GridFSDBFile> files = PlayJongo.gridfs().find(filename);
```

The relevant code in the driver in the GridFS class is below:

```
/**
 * finds a list of files matching the given query
 * @param query
 * @param sort
 * @return
 * @throws MongoException 
 */
public List<GridFSDBFile> find( DBObject query , DBObject sort){
    List<GridFSDBFile> files = new ArrayList<GridFSDBFile>();

    DBCursor c = null;
    try {
        c = _filesCollection.find( query );
        if (sort != null) {
            c.sort(sort);
        }
        while ( c.hasNext() ){
            files.add( _fix( c.next() ) );
        }
    } finally {
         if (c != null){
             c.close();
         }
    }
    return files;
}

protected GridFSDBFile _fix( Object o ){
    if ( o == null )
        return null;

    if ( ! ( o instanceof GridFSDBFile ) )
        throw new RuntimeException( "somehow didn't get a GridFSDBFile" );

    GridFSDBFile f = (GridFSDBFile)o;
    f._fs = this;
    return f;
}
```

I'm using play! 2.1 with the Jongo wrapper but they shouldn't affect it as I'm accessing gridFS directly using mongodb's java driver.

Whats odd is if i debug than the data I actually want is in the object but its not the object that the driver is expecting:

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. If you access the fs.files collection using the jongo api it breaks further access to the gridFS file system, even if you use the mongoDB driver directly.

A patch has been issue but is not yet integrated into a release

Patch: https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/commit/0d27ba3ebfd065e7bf4ad323ee21059b762b512e

Answer (score 0):

More details on this bug fix:

1. Save the state of the 'fs.files' collection before fs.files.find() by

   Class save = fs.files.getObjectClass();
2. Restore the state afterward

   fs.files.setObjectClass(save)